# Go Auto-Recompile and Reload Server on file change

Tags: go, guard

I know AppEngine does this, but I'm not coding for it.

I tried using `Guard` from Ruby world, to listen on changes on `.go` files, and execute the following commands:

```
killall foo
go build -race
./foo &
```

But it never sends `foo` into background, it just hangs indefinitely.

How are you guys solving this problem? Solution has to be cross-platform too (GNU/Linux and Mac).

Comment: Not really a "Go" question, have you tried: `nohup ./foo > /var/log/foo/out.log &`

Answer (score 37):

Another option, if you have nodejs installed on your machine

install [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) with -g `npm i -g nodemon`

go to your code dir and run:

```
nodemon --watch './**/*.go' --signal SIGTERM --exec 'go' run cmd/MyProgram/main.go
```

This will send SIGTERM every time any `.go` files changes and will run `go run cmd/Myprogram/main.go`

Fully cross platform.

Comment: However, installing `npm` *correctly* can be tricky (and platform-specific).  `nvm` may be the best way to get `npm`: [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16151018/86967)

Comment: NPM is fully cross platform, if you are using npm with sudo you just installed it wrongly. NVM doesn't solve cross platform it solves versioning

Comment: works like a charm as it does in the node world.

Comment: In my case I had to specify the extension with -e:
`nodemon -e go --signal SIGTERM --exec 'go' run .`

Comment: Perfect. EXactly what I was looking for

Comment: On Windows I had to use SIGKILL instead of SIGTERM

Comment: in my case the command is not work successfully, I removed the `'` sign from the command, The end result of the command was as follows: `nodemon --watch ./**/*.go --signal SIGTERM --exec go run server.go`, my nodemon ver: **2.0.20**, my nodejs ver: **18.12.1**

Comment: On Windows 10 (powershell) instead of using SIGTERM, I omitted the --signal option, nodemon would use the default kill signal, worked as expected. (While SIGTERM won't restart the process properly.)

Comment: This is just a modification to the above helpful comments. On windows, in your commandline (terminal), navigate to the root of your project(current directory) where you have your main.go file and run;
nodemon --watch './**/*.go' --signal SIGKILL --exec go run main.go

Answer (score 29):

A friend wrote a simple Compile Daemon for go, worked like a charm for my own small net/http-projects.

You can find the repository here: https://github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon

Comment: It looks like it doesn't run the binaries, it only builds them. Is there another solution to get us the rest of the way?

Comment: This is answer is old but CompileDaemon does run it too with `CompileDaemon -command="./MyProgram -my-options"`

Comment: Compile Daemon is nice, but as I understand it can't run command without build. In some cases you just need to run "go run ./my_app" without build it first. In such cases, Compile Daemon is useless.

Comment: Can't install with go 1.18 / 1.19: https://github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon/issues/75

Comment: Here to replace CompileDaemon because I often get this error in PowerShell, Git Bash, CMD, etc: `watcher.Error:Windows system assumed buffer larger than it is, events have likely been missed.`

Answer (score 21):

There is a go version of nodemon: https://github.com/mitranim/gow

```
go install github.com/mitranim/gow@latest
```

usage

```
# Start and restart on change
gow run .

# Pass args to the program
gow run . arg0 arg1 ...

# Run subdirectory
gow run ./subdir

# Vet and re-vet on change; verbose mode is recommended
gow -v vet

# Clear terminal on restart
gow -c run .

# Specify file extension to watch
gow -e=go,mod,html run .

# Help
gow -h
```

Comment: Only works for Linux?

Comment: It works like a charm; I tested it on Mac. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 16):

I've recently discovered a [reflex](https://github.com/cespare/reflex) tool. It's fast and works like a charm. It is very similar to nodemon (from nodejs world) and guard (from ruby world).

Most of the time I'm using it similar to below:

`reflex -d none -s -R vendor. -r \.go$ -- go run cmd/server/main.go`

But it maybe more convenient to have it's options in a file like .reflex, with contents like this:

`-d none -s -R vendor. -r \.go$`

So then you just run it like this

`reflex $(cat .reflex) -- go run cmd/server/main.go`

You can do same thing to "hot reload" tests:

`reflex $(cat .reflex) -- go test ./... -v`

There is also a config option where you can specify a number of commands you run same time, but I don't really use it.

Comment: It looks like `reflex` (now) has a way to read a configuration file directly.  Your third example could be rewritten as `reflex -c .reflex -- go run cmd/server/main.go`.

Comment: thanks @ESV, didn't notice that change, good to know that.

Comment: And it's Linux only. :(

Comment: well, it works on OSX as well, never tried Windows though.

Answer (score 14):

You can also try out Gin by Codegangsta. It's fire and forget.

https://github.com/codegangsta/gin

EDIT:
I prefer [CompileDaemon](https://github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon) nowadays. Gin sometimes won't accept requests

Answer (score 7):

I used a tool called [entr](http://eradman.com/entrproject/)

To install `brew install entr` (mac)
or, `sudo apt-get install entr` (linux)

To recompile & run on `.go` file changes, run the following command ...

```sh
ls **/*.go | entr go run main.go
```

Comment: the problem with this command is that it does not catch new files. It only watches files listed in the preliminary ls.

Comment: `ls -d **/*.go | entr -d go run main.go` this works for new files too...more at https://eradman.com/entrproject/

Answer (score 6):

Best option is to install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) on your machine and use `nodemon` package

install [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) with -g `sudo npm install -g nodemon`
Also use sudo to avoid any write permission

Now go to your program dir and run:

```
nodemon --watch './**/*.go' --signal SIGTERM --exec 'go' run path-to-the-main-file-of-go-program-with-extension
```

This will send SIGTERM every time any `.go` files changes and will run `go run main-go-file-of-program-with-extension`

Fully cross platform.
This will work for any programming language by just changing the command as

```
nodemon --watch './**/*.extension-of-programming-file-without-preceeding-dot' --signal SIGTERM --exec 'go' run path-to-the-main-file-of-program-with-extension
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `nodemon` for this. Simply create a nodemon.json file containing your configuration, files to watch, files to ignore, and command to execute when a file changes. Something like this configuration.

nodemon.json

```
{
  "watch": ["*"],
  "ext": "go graphql",
  "ignore": ["*gen*.go"],
  "exec": "go run scripts/gqlgen.go && (killall -9 server || true ) && go run ./server/server.go"
}
```

You do require nodejs for this to work. 
But its far better then any other tool I've used so far that are go specific.

Comment: This is a lifesaver, thanks. Using nodemon is so much better than the standard appengine filewatcher. Here's the exec command that works for me for the interested

"python dev_appserver.py app/ --automatic_restart=no"

Answer (score 4):

While writing go in linux environment, you can watch the changed files and restart automatically without installing any additional programs in the local.

```
find . -name "*.go" | grep '\.go' | entr -r go run .
```

or

```
find . -name "*.go" | entr -r go run .
```

Comment: This worked for me. You can also drop `grep` by using `find . -name "*.go"` instead.

Comment: I prefer this solution over nodemon because nodemon is throwing an error of `file watch limit reached`. I know we can increase the limit but for me it requires sudo access which I don't have.

Answer (score 3):

After scrolling through the internet in search of a simple solution that was using standard linux tools (inotify & bash), I ended up creating this simple bash script that does the job.

I tested it in a container running golang:1.12 and using `go run .` to serve files. read the script before using it, as it kills the `go run` processes depending on a folder name, and if there are conflicts with other processes that you run it might kill them.

```
#!/bin/bash

go run . &
while inotifywait --exclude .swp -e modify -r . ;
do
    # find PID of the file generated by `go run .` to kill it. make sure the grep does not match other processes running on the system
    IDS=$(ps ax | grep "/tmp/go-build" | grep "b001/exe/main" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $1}')
    if [ ! -z "$IDS" ]
    then
        kill $IDS;
    fi
    go run . &
done;
```

Comment: this works only if the program is modified in the current directory tree. If a package is located elsewhere in the fs is modified, this wont restart the app. smthg like this is smarter https://github.com/clementauger/grelot

Comment: I love the --exclude .swp...   VI fun here.

Answer (score 2):

there are 2 main contenders here in GO world `fresh` & `glide`

But I will go with `Fresh` https://github.com/gravityblast/fresh

Comment: Why did you choose `fresh` over `glide`?  What makes either of these more compelling to you than `CompileDaemon` or `reflex`?

Comment: `fresh` is unmaintained now 

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me, maybe it will work for you too.

```
nodemon --exec go run index.go --signal SIGTERM
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use [Fresh](https://github.com/gravityblast/fresh) and [Realize](https://github.com/oxequa/realize) but some error happened.

So I use [Air](https://github.com/cosmtrek/air) and works great so far

##### Summarized Steps:

1. Install with go install (for go v1.22 or higher)

   ```
   go install github.com/cosmtrek/air
   ```
2. go to project directory and initialize `.air.toml` default config file

   ```
   air init
   ```
3. run air

   ```
   air
   ```

More explanation available on [Air github repository](https://github.com/cosmtrek/air)

Answer (score -1):

if anyone’s still looking for a solution, i wrote some shell scripts to do this and it’s usable via a docker environment, the repos at https://github.com/zephinzer/golang-dev